# What model is my audition guitar and why is the name slayer engraved into the side

Tags: guitar

[image]

I bought this guitar and neither me nor the guy I bought it from knew anything about it I was hoping someone else might

Comment: It's possible that the "Slayer" mention on the guitar is a reference to the band [Slayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slayer).

Answer (score 4):

It's an Audition semi-acoustic (no specific model, unless there's a sticker under the upper F-hole). Made in Japan by Teisco during the 1960's, and sold by Woolworths.